# How to export the contents of the string or textbox to txt file that remains the same format (If string has 5 lines, txt file will has 5 lines)?

Tags: c#

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    FileInfo Myfile = new FileInfo(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
    StreamWriter wri = Myfile.CreateText();
    wri.WriteLine(Richtextbox.Text);
    wri.Close();
}
```

When I export to a text file, all the lines in richtextbox stick into one line. I donnot know how to  keep file txt'content same as in richtextbox'content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (var line in Richtextbox.Lines)
{
    wri.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SaveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.savefile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
Richtextbox.SaveFile(FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```